# Confusion about Boost Python Numpy in CMake

Tags: boost, cmake, alpine-linux

I have a CMake project which uses the boost libraries `python` and `numpy` with the relevant CMake sections below:

```
find_package(Boost 1.65 QUIET COMPONENTS python38 numpy38)
find_package(Python 3 COMPONENTS Development)

target_include_directories(my_target
  PUBLIC
  ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS)
)

target_link_libraries(my_target
  Boost::python38
  Boost::numpy38
  Python::Python
)
```

This works well under Ubuntu 20.04 with boost 1.71, python 3.8.5 and cmake 3.16.
I cannot make it work in my build pipeline running alpine with boost 1.72, python 3.8.10 and cmake 3.18 however, as the boost component `numpy38` cannot be found.

In ubuntu, I specifically have a package `libboost-numpy-dev`, where no corresponding package appears to exist under alpine. [Apparently](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy) the boost module NumPy is deprecated anyway and should be included in the python module, so maybe alpine is just enforcing this?

However, without the `numpy38` component I get `undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python5numpy7ndarray9get_flagsEv`. From the namespace this suggests to be part of `Boost::python38`, but it obviously is not.

So my questions:

1. **Am I supposed to have a separate Boost::numpy component which is not part of Boost::python?**
2. **If yes, how do I get it in alpine?**